# Pass empty regex replacement in Azure group claim

Tags: regex, azure, saml, dispose, group

[image: Customize Setup]

I am using SAML group claim for provisioning users into a group in applications upon login. These groups will have a prefix in Azure, and that prefix should be dropped when they login so that they are assigned to the correct group.

Example:
Group name: Prefix-Artemis
Application group name: Artemis

I am attempting to use the "Apply regex replace to groups claim content" and I am coming up a bit short. I did a test and just put a $ in the Regex replacement pattern and renamed a group in the app to have a $ in front of their name and it correctly assigned a user to that group upon login (but obviously our groups in apps do not start with a $). So, if I could somehow pass nothing I think it would work correctly.

I have tried "" and '' and it does not work, I assume it is passing through ''groupName. Any tips

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct value, fill in `{1}`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).